# how to use render json: with active-model-serializers gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers

i use gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0' for formart json with gem versionist for version api manager

i write clone controller for export json like this :

```
#app/v1/products_controller
class V1::ProductsController < V1::BaseController
  start_offset = params[:offset]
  max_products = Product.all.size
  products = Product.all.limit(Settings.limit_products_json).offset start_offset
  next_number = start_offset.to_i + Settings.limit_products_json

  if next_number < max_products
    render json: {
      products: products,
      next_products: Settings.next_products_json + next_number.to_s,
      product_end: Settings.product_end_false_json
    }
  else
    render json: {
      products: products,
      product_end: Settings.product_end_true_json,
      product_end_reason: Settings.product_end_reason_json
    }
  end
end
```

and in serializers folder i write:

```
#serializers/v1/product_serializer.rb
class V1::ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

and result is all attributes of Product to json. But I only want limit result of product to `:id` and `:name` as i wrote in class `V1::ProductSerializer`. How can i do that? Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know active_model_serializers does not support versioning out of box. Either rename your serializer to `ProductSerializer` or specify `each_serializer` option explicitly and put your other parameters in meta:

```
meta = if next_number < max_products
  {
    next_products: Settings.next_products_json + next_number.to_s,
    product_end: Settings.product_end_false_json
  }
else
  {
    product_end: Settings.product_end_true_json,
    product_end_reason: Settings.product_end_reason_json
  }
end

render json: products, each_serializer: V1::ProductSerializer, meta: meta
```